# Assign JSON value to property in C#

Tags: c#, json

From an API I receive a JSON-object that looks like this:

```
{
  "wind" : {
    "speed" : 7.31,
    "deg" : 187.002
  },
  "rain" : {
    "3h" : 0
  },
  "clouds" : {
    "all" : 92
  },
  "coord" : {
    "lon" : 139,
    "lat" : 35
  },
  "dt" : 1369824698,
  "id" : 1851632,
  "cod" : 200,
  "weather" : [
    {
      "id" : 804,
      "main" : "clouds",
      "icon" : "04n",
      "description" : "overcast clouds"
    }
  ],
  "main" : {
    "humidity" : 89,
    "temp_max" : 292.04,
    "temp_min" : 287.04,
    "temp" : 289.5,
    "pressure" : 1013
  },
  "sys" : {
    "country" : "JP",
    "sunrise" : 1369769524,
    "sunset" : 1369821049
  },
  "name" : "Shuzenji"
}
```

I would like to assign two of these values to my class:

```
public class Weather {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Temp { get; set; }
}
```

The name I can assign like this:

```
weather.Name = TheJSON.name.ToString();
```

But the temp is trickier, because it's nested inside the "main"-array. I´ve seen many examples on how to do this in Javascript but not so much in C#. Thanks!

Comment: have you converted the json string to json object ?

Comment: The answer seems so simple, I'm not sure if I'm missing something or not.  You just want `TheJSON.main.temp`, right?

Comment: Main is not an array. It is an object, so TheJSON.main.temp.ToString().

Comment: Thats right coding-gorilla.
I´ll be back in a while. thanks

Comment: @jyparask Thank you! Worked fine and kinda obvious when I saw it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main is not an array. It is an object, so

```
TheJSON.main.temp.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to work with JSON data is to deserialize them as C# objects and directly use them in your application. You can use a tool like [JSON C# Class Generator](https://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/) to automatically generate the C# class from the JSON data. Once you have your C# classes generated, you can deserialize the JSON string using the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText); The generated code requires [Newtonsoft Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) which you can easily add as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).

If you save your JSON content in D:\test.json, you can use the following code to access the values using the C# objects generated. The example below is to just give you an idea on the usage.

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.json");
var weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Weather>(json);
Console.WriteLine(weather.Name);
Console.WriteLine(weather.Sys.Country);
```